# Create firebase audience where count of one event is greater than count of other event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have two events, say 'event1' and 'event2' with their respective count.I I need to create an audience where count of 'event1' is greater than count of 'event2'. Basically I need an audience with condition something like 'count of event1 > count of event2'. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can increment 'event1' everytime you increment 'event2'.

This way if your event1 count is 2 and event2 count is 1, and you increment event2 with 1 then it will increment event1 to 3 and event2 to 2.

Comment: I am already maintaining count this way. My problem is while creating audience, one can add condition that event1 or event2 is greater than , less than , equals to any value.There is no way that I can create an audience with condition 'count of event1 > count of event2'. I have edited my answer to explain this better.

Comment: I am sorry but can you elaborate a little more.